# How can I change the layout when the user login with Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Hi I am trying to change the layout when the user starts a session, the session works fine but if I add this code:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    @extends('backend.layouts.app')
@else
    @extends('layouts.app')
@endif
```

It does not recognize the Auth::check I mean it displays both layouts one over the another one so I wonder how can I do it? or fix that code?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you use a Ternary, or set the value as a string? Something like `@extends(Auth::check() ? 'backend.layouts.app' : 'layouts.app')` or `@php $layout = Auth::check() ? 'backend.layouts.app' : 'layouts.app' @endphp`, then `@extends($layout)`? The issue might be with having 2 instances of `@extends()`.

Comment: @TimLewis no it did not work :(, when I do that if I did not start the session it works, then when I start the session it does not change it keeps the frontend layout

Comment: I'm not really sure what are you trying to do, but this is probably a bad design and you should be doing at routing time, not in the views.

Comment: try to use helper auth() like this @if(auth()->check())

Answer (score 0):

That's not a right way. Try with this:

In your contoller that returns the view, check if the user is logged. This is an example.

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $layout = Auth::check() ? 'backend.layouts.app' : 'layouts.app';

    return view('welcome', compact('layout'));
});
```

And in your view put this

```
@extends($layout)
```

Or you can use the next way:

```
@extends(Auth::check() ? 'backend.layouts.app' : 'layouts.app')
```